Partial dependency plots
I am trying to use SVM algorithm for a classification problem, here is my code below.
I would like to get importance value of each variable on the fitted function using (PDP). I have the graph, but don't have the value, to see how percentage is the contribution of each variable on fitted function?
How can I show the importance of each variable in each graph.
Here is the code:
data2 = read.csv(file.choose())

pima.svm <- ksvm(High ~ ., data = data2, type = "C-svc", kernel = "rbfdot",
                 C = 0.5, prob.model = TRUE)

# Partial dependence 
grid.arrange(

  partial(pima.svm, pred.var = "soil", plot = TRUE, train = data2, rug=TRUE),
  partial(pima.svm, pred.var = "tree", plot = TRUE, train = data2, rug = TRUE,chull = TRUE),
        
    #partial(pima.svm, pred.var = c("soil", "tree"), plot = TRUE, train = data1),
  ncol = 3)


Please do not post links to external images, instead provide applicable code snippets and images here. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

WIthout a reproducible question, it's difficult to help. I don't see anything in the kernlab library. You could use the caret package with train(..., method = "svmRadial"). This method calls kernlab::kvsm(). caret is a wrapper for things like bootstrapping, analysis, and adds more robust functions regarding things like variable importance. You can read their user manual here. (That's a great machine learning resource even if you don't use caret.) If you would like, I can add an answer using this package (using generic data).

Thanks for your answer. if you could add an answer using my data, would be pretty helpful using the caret package.
Thanks.
Here is a chunk of my data: dependent variable is "High" and independent variables are "soil, tree, GLCM,
soil tree GLCM High
849.1 849 1.3 0
298.1 298 1.4 0
521.1 521 1.4 1
860.1 860 1.8 0
131 131 1.4 0
1097.1 1097 1.6 0
410.1 410 1.4 0
283.1 283 1.2 0
832.1 832 1.4 0
224.1 224 1 0
387.1 387 1.3 0
238.1 238 1.5 1
780.1 780 1.4 0
298.1 298 1.5 0
910.1 910 1.6 0
193.1 193 1.1 0
867.1 867 1.6 0
529.1 529 1.6 0
538.1 538 1.7 0
849.1 849 1.3 0
